SQL Server, Отношения между таблицами, внешний и первичный ключ
я только начинаю изучать СУБД, поэтому возможно мой вопрос достаточно глуп. Так вот:
Мне нужно создать две таблицы, первая будет содержать: порядковый номер, логин пользователя, пароль пользователя, id пользователя. Вторая таблица: порядковый номер, id пользователя, дату и время захода в систему пользователя. И мне нужно настроить внешний ключ, чтобы при входе в систему эти данные автоматически заполнялись.

первая будет содержать: порядковый номер, логин пользователя, пароль пользователя, id пользователя. Возникает сразу вопрос - нафига вам ТРИ поля, каждое из которых просто по смыслу и уникально, и NOT NULL, и соответственно однозначно идентифицирует пользователя? Вторая таблица: порядковый номер, id пользователя, дату и время захода в систему пользователя. опять же вопрос - нафига отдельная таблица для того, чтобы хранить всего одно значащее поле, штамп времени (последнего) входа?

понятие порядкового номера в базе данных - принципиальная чушь, которая имеет корни в бюрократических привычках нумеровать строчки таблицы. Порядок записей определяется запросом, так что лучше сразу привыкайте, что в БД таких полей быть не должно. Хранение пароля пользователя в таблице - явное нарушение защиты.

@Anna, крайне рекомендую почитать: https://vk.com/doc26211044_480972228?hash=qfs3O3qWDCpi1x1Zi8ht4z9EzMA5JDpEHV3ziC13Lc4&dl=Hcll0Y1WoAHuu7UPqmBJ9NBOOBalpCeilmvbauDo3hg  Коннолли Томас, Бегг Каролин. Базы данных. Проектирование, реализация и сопровождение. Теория и практика
